# How to create list of output data corresponding to input value

Tags: python-3.x

For an example,the arithmetic operations like

```
    x=10
    a=x+2
```

Requirement: The output value has to be stored in the separate list corresponding to input value. When we put `x` value is 10 it as to store in list `b`, and next input 20.. and so an are store in the list `b`. Same way the output of a also stores in list `c`

```
    b=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70]# these are series of x inputs  
    c=[12,22,32,42,52,62,72]# these are corresponding ouputs of x input
```

```
because i need these b and c lists to plot the graphs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
r = 10
b =[]
c = []
for i in range(r):
    num = int(input("Enter plot x:"))
    b.append(num)
    c.append(num + 2)

print('b '+ b)
print('c '+ c)
```

Comment: Thanks Madhan, 
Unfortunately, your answer not fullfilled my requirement

Comment: I do some operation corrosponding input value like 10 then store it in to new list b=[10,]
same time the output as to store in c=[12] and then next the input and outputs as to appened in to b and c list like
b=[10,20...]
c=[12,22,,,]

Comment: I have updated the answer, can you check is this what you ask